# Error in importing IDP metadata into websphere application server 8.5

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, websphere-8, adfs3.0

We are getting

> java.lang.Instantiation

exception when importing IDP metadata xml into websphere application server 8.5. IDP is ADFS 3.0. We are following the steps given in [Websphere 8.5 saml setup](https://developer.ibm.com/digexp/docs/docs/customization-administration/step-step-guide-implement-saml-2-0-portal-8-5/).

Command used in wsadmin is:

> AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata('-idpMetadataFileName
>   "C:/federationmetadata.xml" -idpId 1 -ssoId 1 -signingCertAlias
>   idpCert1')

The error stack trace in command prompt is shown below:

```
wsadmin>AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata('-idpMetadataFileName "C:/federationmeta
data.xml" -idpId 1 -ssoId 1 -signingCertAlias idpCert1')
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata('-idpMeta
dataFileName "C:/federationmetadata.xml" -idpId 1 -ssoId 1 -signingCertAlias uma
ng')"; exception information:
com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in ?
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: java.lang.InstantiationError: java.lang
.InstantiationError: oasis.names.tc.saml._2_0.metadata.RoleDescriptorType

        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminCmdController.executeCmd(Admin
CmdController.java:1914)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminCmdController.processCmd(Admin
CmdController.java:318)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminCmdProxyHandler.invoke(AdminCm
dProxyHandler.java:92)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminCmdProxyBase.__method3(AdminCm
dProxyBase.java:53)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.adminCommand.AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata(Unk
nown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java
)
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java)
        at org.python.core.PyInstance.invoke(PyInstance.java)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx56.f$0(<input>:1)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx56.call_function(<input>)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java)
        at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java)
        at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine$BSFPythonInterpreter.runcode(
Unknown Source)
        at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(InteractiveInterpret
er.java)
        at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(InteractiveInterpret
er.java)
        at com.ibm.bsf.engines.jython.JythonEngine.iexec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager$7.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:417
)
        at com.ibm.bsf.BSFManager.iexec(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.interactive(AbstractShell.java:139
8)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.AbstractShell.run(AbstractShell.java:2298)
        at com.ibm.ws.scripting.WasxShell.main(WasxShell.java:1172)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithEx
ception(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandl
e.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runAppli
cation(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ec
lipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.ja
va:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.ja
va:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.jav
a:400)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:163)

com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException
: java.lang.InstantiationError: java.lang.InstantiationError: oasis.names.tc.sam
l._2_0.metadata.RoleDescriptorType
```

Anyone having idea about this error? We are using administrator id to run wsadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only information we really need to know is ADFS server's certificate that sign the SAML. So we took the X509 Certificate from ADFS server, and manually imported into WAS's default trust store(CellDefaultTrustStore). We manually configured IDP by adding following attributes to interceptor properties. We are able to connect to ADFS now.

sso_1.idp_1.entityID

sso_1.idp_1.certAlias

sso_1.idp_1.singleSignOnUrl